# What is the right application pool for Net 4.5 for web app on IIS?

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7.5

I have installed .NET 4.5 on a computer. then try to deploy a new web app with Net 4.5 to IIS, but only 2 application pool available:

```
.NET Framework v2.0.50727
.NET Framework v4.0.30319
```

Not sure if v4.0.30319  is the right application pool for the app on .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

yes .NET Framework v4.0.* is the right application pool, The .NET 4.5 is not a major new version.

Comment: 2.0 replaced whereas 3.0 extended; I take it that 4.0 replaces stuff but 4.5 just extends?